# OCUnit : changing the user's locale for testing

Tags: ios, unit-testing, locale, ocunit

This is a simple question : is it possible to change the locale while unit testing ?

I'd like to check that my label is "Monday" in english and "lundi" in french for example.

Comment: locale testing should not be part of unit tests.

Answer (score 2):

The situation you describe sounds more like an integration test than a unit test; you're changing the environment in which the app runs and ensuring that the app's behaviour changes accordingly. It's the sort of thing I'd check with [UIAutomation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AnalysisTools/Conceptu%E2%80%A6).

In a unit test situation, you might have a method that prepares the label text: you can create arbitrary [NSLocale](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSLocale_Class/Reference/Reference.html) instances, and assert that the correct strings table is used for each locale in your test fixtures.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. Actually what I wanted to do was more about Date Components and the first day of the week. I don't remember exactly what I wanted to do though.